# What do "bs", "bc" and all the other abbreviations mean in "Recent Posts with Most Vote Velocity" page?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

The /tools/vote-hot/ page of the 10k tools breaks down votes by type. However, the two letter abbreviations are far from being self-explanatory.

[image: Screenshot of the page, featuring clear comments like "up:11" and not so clear comments like "fv:1"]

I guess "up" are upvotes, "fv" are favorites, "dn" (not pictured) are downvotes. I can't quite guess what the rest is, however, and [my normal approach of hovering is useless here](http://xkcd.com/55/).

What kinds of votes are listed on these pages? What does each abbreviation mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Had to go look at the code for this because I couldn't parse some of them either.

ac = Accepted
up = UpVote
dn = DownVote
of = Offensive Flag
fv = Favorite
cl = Vote to Close
op = Vote to Reopen
bs = Bounty Started (on questions only)
bc = Bounty Closed (this vote is cast on the answer that receives the bounty)
dl = Vote to Delete
ud = Vote to Undelete
sp = Spam Flag
md = Inform Moderator Flag

Comment: Unfair advantage!  :)

Comment: @Bill the Lizard:  Every job has its perks :)

Comment: Any chance of getting hover text added?

Comment: @Bill: a dev actually was the only person who could possibly answer this question fully :)