# Voting more than 40 times on first day of the week, a bug?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

I have just checked [weekly voting statistic](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters&filter=week) and it seems that some people where able to vote more than 40 times.
How is this even possible, since (at least in USA) week started today?
Does this depend on time zone?

Comment: Interesting find. Maybe the votes were on questions that were subsequently deleted? Cody Gray's detailed statistic on his [profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) shows 40 votes, as it should

Comment: Accurate counting remains an elusive feature at SE.  REST strikes again.

Comment: Vote early in the week, vote often!

Comment: I wish you'd cited some examples; harder to look now that it is UTC Monday and many people have legitimate >40

Comment: @Marc Gravell: When I checked last night, I believe Cody Gray was showing as 43 votes, my account was showing as 42 on the user stats page, although my profile was showing 40 (I've no idea which was correct).  I've haven't had any accounts merged... I did flag a spam post though and some of my downvoted posts have been closed / deleted...

Comment: Hmm, I suppose I was at the top of that voter list with 45 votes earlier in the day? I don't have multiple accounts, so there was definitely no merging going on. I did vote down a number of questions that I subsequently voted to close and/or delete. But I didn't think this affected the daily allotment of votes.

Comment: @Cody @forsvarir - hmmm; I wonder if we aren't filtering the vote types correctly; we're investigating (this will be a UI thing, not a "too many votes" thing)

Comment: @Marc Gravel, @Waffles: So I'm supposed to be showing 82 votes and Cody Gray is supposed to show 100 votes, even though it's only the second day of the week?

Comment: @forsvarir - 80 isn't overkill. The rest may be caching - see @waffles comment

Comment: @forsvarir note we haven't deployed yet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, good catch, our top voters filter on the users page was not filtering out votes other than up and down.

Fixed now.

Comment: to be deployed soon

Comment: What other types of votes are there?

Comment: all of the other ones, accepts and flags ... etc

Comment: @Cody http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63359/what-do-bs-bc-and-all-the-other-abbreviations-mean-in-recent-posts-with-mos/63363#63363

Comment: @badp: Fascinating, thanks. I had no idea all of those were counted as "votes", at least not in the same sense as up and down votes.

Comment: @waffles Right now the vote breakdown on my [profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/83075/banang) on SO tells me I've voted 41 times today. This is probably relating to the same bug, but I'd thought I'd let you know non the less...

Answer (score 5):

One way this is possible is when people have multiple accounts and we merge them.

Should not be particularly *common*, though.