# Vox Populi isn't applied retroactively?

Tags: support, badges, voting

A new badge [Vox Populi was introduced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/147/vox-populi), but isn't this applied retroactively? I had hit 40-vote [limit earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90058/daily-vote-limt-hit-before-reaching-actual-counts). Or is this applicable to those votes after the [new changes were done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes/90256#90256)?

Comment: I can confirm that it's definitely not retroactive. I hit 40 votes yesterday (as apparently became an interesting [topic of discussion here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90384/voting-more-than-40-times-on-first-day-of-the-week-a-bug)), but I was forced to hit that limit *again* today in order to earn the Vox Populi badge.

Comment: @Cody Gray - Sad day, being forced to vote and all.  Sarcasm aside, I don't think this is problem...

Comment: @reem: I didn't mean to imply that it was a bad thing, nor that I was unhappy about having to vote. I was simply providing confirmation of Sathya's observations that the badge in question did not appear to be applied retroactively. I agree there's no reason it should be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is by design, I explicitly cut out anything that happened earlier than yesterday.

This is not purely an evil scheme to get people to vote more. The rules changed, its a bit trickier to get the badge now. Also I wanted to avoid old account merges resulting in people getting the badge. The meta flood would be huge.

Comment: Question superseded one year later by http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123172/248268 :)