# Vox Populi, Civic Duty, and Electorate badges being awarded en masse

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, electorate-badge, voting-badges

I've just been awarded the Vox Populi badge on Meta Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow, Gaming & WordPress. I don't think I've voted once today, let alone 40 times on each site.

Reports indicate that this is affecting all of the voting-related badges, including Vox Populi, Civic Duty, and Electorate.

[image]

Comment: It happened to me too.

Comment: I was awarded this on Meta Super User and MSO, despite using only 30 votes this entire month on either site.

Comment: [Looks like a whole bunch of people just earned it (including me)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/K6FrU.png)

Comment: Can one check on the votes you have casted?

Comment: @ziggystar Yeah its on bottom right of the summary of your profile page. For example you've had 3 this week and 26 this month on SO

Comment: I actually thought I earned it a long time ago but it didn't show up; I figured it was playing catchup--perhaps not.

Comment: Presumably a consequence of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions/123048#123048). Definitely a bug, I got it on sites where I know I haven't voted on that many deleted posts and I don't even have the Suffrage badge.

Comment: I'm calling badge catch-up job with the added twist of a new cartesian product bug. Vegas has the odds at 5:2

Comment: I'm keeping it, you can pluck it from my cold lifeless hand when I am lying in my grave. But then ask yourself - would you seize back a mere piece of bronze from a dead man?

Comment: It's on other meta's too. See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/827/759

Comment: I see my name and part of my species in the freehand circle. **I have been immortalized.**

Comment: @animuson: Looks fine to me...

Comment: [It's meta madness.](http://i.imgur.com/lK7Gv.jpg)

Comment: This is especially disconcerting because it implies activity on your account that you know you did not yourself perform. (Which of course makes the user feel like their account was compromised, which in turn implies that StackOverflow itself is insecure in some way.) Obviously this is a pretty devastating bug for those it affects. Not all users will know to come here to find out about it.

Comment: @livingtech Yeah, that was my main concern too.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

We just deployed a change that affects the voting badges.  This is why you see a number of these badges being awarded.

For more information about this change, you can see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/140548).

Note that there is a bug with Vox Populi only that is awarding too many of them, beyond the expected more for retroactive awards, and a fix is being deployed now.  The erroneous awards there will be cleaned up shortly.

Comment: The other two are fine, aren't they? As their required votes are accumulative over any time span.

Comment: Can we keep them for posterity?

Comment: @H.B. yes, Electorate and Civic Duty are correct.

Comment: Can you run the same "bug" on the Legendary badge?

Comment: This was my screw up, sorry guys!  The badges will be fixed (and revoked where needed) in just a moment.

Comment: Wow that got fixed quick, it's already gone.

Comment: Dominus dedit, Dominus abstulit...

Comment: 29648 awarded down to 2497 awarded.

Comment: Just FYI: while you fixed the mis-awarded badge, I still received the pop-up saying I'd earned the Vox Populi badge (even though I hadn't earned it, and you had already cleaned up the mis-award).

Comment: Nothing like real-time accountability with several thousand users to keep you on the edge of your seat. Not sure I'm envying any of the SE devs.

Comment: @MichaelKohne yup, step 1 was stopping the badge being awarded.  step 2 is the notifications.

Comment: 2497 awarded up to 2682 awarded. That looks better.

Comment: @MichaelKohne notifications should be gone now.

Comment: Everything looks fine on Stack Overflow, but I still see an erroneous badge notification on my stackexchange.com user profile.

Comment: @SteveTjoa - that's the aggregator, the reason that wasn't addressed is a) it's *really* hard, and b) that's getting a full backfill very soon, so it'll be corrected then (as part of fixing other aggregation hiccups this week)

Comment: I've lost the Vox Populi after earning it genuinely. It's not a huge problem but I just happened to earn it the other day.