# Did Stack Overflow delete my history?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, meta

Yesterday I received a badge on Stack Overflow erroneously. I posted a question on Meta to see if that was a bug (using the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag), yet today there is no record that I ever received the badge or ever asked the question on Meta... Feels kinda like a conspiracy... Can anyone fill me in on how this all works?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123159/vox-populi-civic-duty-and-electorate-badges-being-awarded-en-masse , I believe a slew of duplicate questions for the same issue got cleaned up.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't correct mistakes, it rewrites time. Looks much cooler

Comment: . . . *maybe* . . . `(>.>)`

Comment: It never happened.  And you'd better keep quiet, if you know what's good for you.

Comment: @Mat thanks for the link. That was exactly the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing it was the Vox Populi badge. There was a [question about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123159/vox-populi-civic-duty-and-electorate-badges-being-awarded-en-masse) — and then there were several more, likely including yours. Normally these would have just been closed as duplicates, but I guess they didn't really add value, and there were too many of them, so they got deleted instead.

As for the badge: There really were badges that were handed out in error (see linked question), but these ended up being rescinded.

Comment: Exactly. Given that there ended up being [**10** duplicates](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IGoum.png), cleaning them up via deletion was a reasonable choice.

Comment: It was the Vox Populi badge. Thanks for helping me out. It was all too vivid in my mind to be a dream...