# Badge count is incorrect on profile page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, profile-page, voting-badges

I see a badge count discrepancy between the badges listed in my profile's Accounts section; it shows extra bronze badges on my Meta and SO accounts. 
[image: boo]

Correct badges:

[image: yay]

[image: yay]

After looking for other examples, I found a couple other users on Meta ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/156620/bavarious), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/63550/peter-mortensen), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/160166/yoda)) who also have SO profiles which list an extra bronze badge on their Meta account.

I thought this might be something that could get solved in the upcoming global recalc on meta but, since my SO account also showed the error, it seemed like a valid question.

---

**EDIT:** Per animuson's comment, this bug is directly related to the Vox Populi badge, or lack thereof. Lacking this badge is common to myself and the four users mentioned (3 above and 1 in my comment below).

Comment: Another user whose profile is more similar to mine (i.e. errors on both SO and meta bronze badge counts): [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52738/gnostradamus)

Comment: I see you don't have the Vox Populi badge, this may be after-effects of the [previous mayhem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123159/141525).

Comment: Ah yes, good catch. That is common among all of the profiles I've mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're looking at your network accounts on a site, e.g. SO from MSO, this is pulling from a network-level cache that can sometimes get out-of-sync.

We periodically fix this cache for all users (which is very expensive), but this is usually not needed. The implementation is such that upon getting another badge or more reputation, the network cache will be fixed to the latest value.

We're running one of these global fixes this weekend - if you're still seeing this after then, let us know.

Comment: In this specific case, the badges were removed outside the normal network activity aggregation framework, so the cache became incorrect.