# Possible bug, displaying badge count of SuperUser-Site

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Badge count is incorrect on profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123715/badge-count-is-incorrect-on-profile-page)

When I am on my profile-page on SO or MSO, my count of SuperUser badges does not show. On Tex-Latex- and SuperUser-Site Profiles everything is fine.

This does not bother me, but it might be a bug worth extinguishing.

[image]

Comment: Dupe of [Badge count is incorrect on profile page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123715) You only *just* got those 7 badges on SU.

Comment: yes, I have only 7 badges - and that is ok, the count is ok and visible - just not under SO or MSO - and that is not the same as an incorrect count - it is not visible, as in my screenshot. Tested with FF 15.01 and IE9.09

Comment: The profiles are cached; when the profile badge count was cached you didn't have any badges yet. Later on, when the cache is updated, you'll see the badge count.

Comment: this state has not changed for quite a while now - my first badge in SU has been autobiographer (sept. 19th). But ok, my Tex-Badge was awarded sept 13th and is synched now. If it really takes this long, this should be fine then.