# bug with badges count

Tags: bug, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Badge count is incorrect on profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123715/badge-count-is-incorrect-on-profile-page)

My badge count appears to be "frozen": even if I earn a new badge in SE-Site "A", the other SE-sites are still showing the old count. Only in the SE-network profile is everything right.

Some weeks ago, I had the same problem with reputation but as I earned more reputation everything got fixed. But now, even when I earned some new badges and reputation nothing happens. I've tried deleting my cookies, using a different browser, refreshed the page 100 times - still nothing!

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: I've seen this, too, if I understand what you're saying.  It's not a question of badges transfering, but rather the count of badges for one site is not correct when displayed in the profile for another site.

Comment: `even if I earn new badge in SE-Site "A", the other SE-sites are showing stil the old count.`  for this answer is **Cache** only

Comment: @ChrisGerken : exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Any idea how can I fix this?
```

You don't need to fix it. It's Cache problem. Most of the users are facing this issue ( including me ). In my Stack Overflow's profile it shows 6 Golden badges while on the other site's profile it shows only 5 Golden Badge.

```
refreshed the page 100 times - still nothing!
```

Deleting cookie or applying <kbd>ctrl+f5</kbd>  is not a solution for such cache issue, because it is from server side.

Let it give time to refresh, it will be back in regular position(count) automatically. You don't need to do anything regarding this.

Answer (score -1):

Each StackExchange site is its own entity. Badges and reputation are not shared between sites, this is by design. The count of rep/badges on one site does not affect the count on others.

If you gain a badge on SE-Site "A", the other SE-sites *shouldn't* show any change to their badge counts.

> Only in the SE-network profile is everything right.

If you're talking about your SE flair, this is the one place designed to summarize your participation in all SE sites. Otherwise, your rep/badges aren't shared.

> Some weeks ago, I had the same problem with the reputation, but as I earned some reputation, everything gone fixed.

Whatever "fix" you think you experience was not a fix. Rep is not and never has been shared between sites.

Comment: My Situation:
I have 14 Badges in Stackoverflow and 14 in SE-Travel-Beta. 
Stackoverflow shows me 14 Badges in the SO, and only 9 In Travel
SE-Travel shows me 14 Badges in Travel, and only 11 In SO

Comment: Ah, you're talking about a caching problem. I completely misunderstood your question.

Comment: my english is not so good, so I couldn't explain exactly what is my problem