# Account summary not updating badges for sites with an ® in their title

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-accounts, badges

I'm aware of the [various caches](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148432/33051) that sit between the [sites and the central database for user data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148636/reputation-display-bug-again) - but I was under the impression that most of the issues around this had been cleared up (at least resolved down to a few minutes) - especially if the points are up to date in the various summaries - so feel free to close this as a dup if it really is.

We've got a [user](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/1276/iprogrammed) who's noticed that their badge count is consistently missing for their LEGO Answers account:

[image: No badges for LEGO Answers]

However, their [Network Profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/2177135/iprogrammed?tab=accounts) is showing all 9 badges:

[image: Badges!]

Clicking through to their accounts on the other sites results in the same lack of badges.

I've just noticed that between me taking the last screenshot and going back to check, iprogrammed's badge count for Ask Different **has incremented to 3** - so clearly some of it's working - but I'd have expected **both** counts to sync at that point?

I've just checked again, and their points summary has updated for LEGO Answers on our site to 195, but the badge count is still blank.

I've also just noticed that [my own summary](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/56/zhaph-ben-duguid) is 2 silver and 9 bronze badges out, and other [users (1s, 3b)](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/99/joubarc) are [even (3s, 14b)](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/36/pcantin) [further (1s, 14b)](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/154/bungeshea) [out (3s, 14b)](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/132/ambo100)

---

Edit to add:

Looks like it's also happening on other sites with a ® symbol in their name - check out some [ExpressionEngine® Answers](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/55/derek-hogue) [users](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/490/brandon-kelly)

Comment: Didn't you know that on LEGO, you have to build your badges yourself using bricks?

Comment: Hopefully if we graduate that will indeed be the case, at the very least they might be rather stud like ;)

Comment: I'm missing 1 silver and 3 bronzes: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/users/11/boltclock

Comment: Yep - I think there's some systemic issue - I think we're *all* missing some badges, I just stopped linking to them after the first few I tried from the Users page ;)

Comment: My reputation is updating but not the badges for the Lego Account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hate that damn symbol! This is somewhere around bug #289 it's caused.

Anyway, fixed in the build that went out earlier, all should be well going forward.

Comment: I know and I'm very sorry about it, but also very grateful it's there ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Nick Craver My Account Badges are Back :)