# I got the civic duty badge 5 votes early

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, voting

The civic duty badge says it's granted for casting 300 votes but I got it after casting only 295 (here on meta).

Maybe it's counting [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90384/voting-more-than-40-times-on-first-day-of-the-week-a-bug/90454#90454) vote types...

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the same thing. I earned my Vox Populi badge one vote early, right after flagging something for moderator attention. It sounds like a related bug to me.

Comment: Or maybe the badge still counts votes against deleted items (because that's what used to be shown on the profile), while the votes cast display on your profile now [only counts votes against non-deleted items](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90495/eeeek-im-missing-650-downvotes-and-300-upvotes/90504#90504)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The badge was counting votes on deleted posts, I just amended it so it consistent with the rest of the counts elsewhere.

Votes now only count on non-deleted posts (towards badges)

Badge will not be fixed retroactively, if you got it a bit early that is fine by me.

Comment: Yikes, someone could stop voting and forever have an invalid badge!  :)

Comment: If anyone feels really strongly that we should take them away I can hack it