# How does someone get to cast more than 40 votes in a day?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, voting-limits

And by someone, I mean that evil feline WesleyDavid:

> [image: ONG WTF Ponies! 42 votes!]

That screenshot was taken just before 4pm PST, i.e. just before 0000 UTC.  That shows KittehHead's votes for the month, which is the same as for the day since it's March 1st.  Just to be sure it wasn't that SE had the time wrong, I tried upvoting something and got the expected "Daily Vote Limit Reached, Please Vote Again in 6 minutes."

So how did Kitteh^H^H^H^H^H^HWesley get 42 votes in one day?

ADDED: It's getting worse... Now it's March 2nd, and Wesley/Cat has 3 extra votes:

> [image: Die Kitty! Die!!]

Now I finally got an extra vote (take that evil kitteh!), but it hasn't helped me understand why:

> [image]

Comment: P.S. Love the 1995 mouse cursor scheme

Comment: I have used the "Dinosaur" mouse theme since NT 3.51 and I have no intention of changing.

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I get more than 40 votes per day?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113044/how-do-i-get-more-than-40-votes-per-day), [Voting more than 40 times on first day of the week, a bug?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90384/voting-more-than-40-times-on-first-day-of-the-week-a-bug)

Comment: Reference to tired meme about the number **42**, Douglas Adams, yada-yada =)

Comment: @CodyGray Those are similar, but not quite the same.  It's probably a similar bug to the one in your second link due to the new system of counting votes on deleted posts.

Comment: If you're a brony, that'd make a nice complement for your faithfulness to the old cursor scheme. (No rule on meta outlaws judging people by their gravatars!)

Comment: Kittehs > Ponies

Comment: Votes are presumably subject to skew in just the same way as rep is. Even after the recent changes, we still have rep skew.

Comment: Solution:  delete @WesleyDavid's account.  Then he won't have voted more than allowed! (:

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff wut

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff It seems like the simplest solution, I'd hate to tie up any worthwhile SE Valued Associate time when simply wiping WesleyDavid's existence out of all SE databases would do it!

Comment: I have recently spent 85 votes on SO, and that's not even the cap. See [PeterJ's activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599751/peterj?tab=topactivity), especially tonight.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Votes on deleted posts do not count towards your daily total.

WesleyDavid did indeed vote 42 times in one day: two of the target posts were deleted before the day ended, allowing him to have those two extra votes.

Comment: This reminds me... Does editing an old post to remove a vote grant you more votes to cast "today"? (Brought up here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4492/vote-manipulation-through-editing)

Comment: If the locked-in vote was cast today, then yes.  If it's older than a day, it won't affect today's quota.

Comment: Why is this status-bydesign though? Clearly, the voting counter is broken.

Comment: @Jarrod if I vote 30 times, then five posts are deleted, and then I vote 10 more times, will I get the Vox Populi badge?

Answer (score 27):

I suspect deleted votes are treated inconsistently, counting towards the stats, but not towards the limit.

There was a recent change related to displaying deleted votes in some statistics: 
["Votes cast" should include votes on deleted contributions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions)

Comment: This appears to be correct. Today, I've cast 36 votes in total (taken from the user info popup), but got a message saying I had 5 left for today. One of the posts I voted down ended up being deleted.

Answer (score 12):

Jarrod's answer is the correct answer, but to spell it out more precisely:

- Votes are counted per day, and the day starts at 0000 UTC
- If a post you voted on during the day is deleted before the end of the day, you will get that vote back

As an extreme illustration:

- One of the auto-delete processes for low-quality questions runs every day at 0300 UTC
- If you search for those low-quality questions and downvote a bunch of them between 0000 and 0300 UTC, you'll get all those votes back.
- For example:  yesterday, I got 70 votes total (30 extra) and earlier this week I had 60 (20 extra).  So instead of 120 votes this week, I've maxed out at 170!

[image: extra votes]

Comment: So you want us to stay awake in the midnight to gain more votes??