# Daily vote cast exceeds 40 in profile display

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does someone get to cast more than 40 votes in a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/how-does-someone-get-to-cast-more-than-40-votes-in-a-day)

I have found [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113044/how-do-i-get-more-than-40-votes-per-day) but couldn't find any answers for this question.

This is [my profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/167909/mithunsatheesh).

In the votes casted for the day section the value is 41. In the badges description I could find

> Vox Populi: Used the maximum 40 votes in a day.(it says the maximum votes that a user can use will be 40. is it?)

How could I vote 41 times if the limit is 40 for a day?

Also voting 40 times Vox Populi badge should be awarded. Now see my badges. I don't have it either.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/167909/mithunsatheesh?tab=badges

Is this an error or am I wrong somewhere?

---

UPDATE: Now I have been awarded the Vox Populi badge. But it was delayed for 1 hour.

Comment: The badge is awarded at the *end* of the day (in 11 hours time). No idea how you've managed to vote 41 times though

Comment: Yep, the badges are awarded by a script that runs sort of randomly. Some of the badge scripts run more often..

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/how-does-someone-get-to-cast-more-than-40-votes-in-a-day/124303#124303

Comment: @ChrisF I don't think it's awarded end of day...

Comment: @Sathya - apparently not, but it is delayed in case you revoke your vote (I've just realised)