# How did I manage to exceed daily votes limit?

Tags: bug, voting, voting-limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does someone get to cast more than 40 votes in a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/how-does-someone-get-to-cast-more-than-40-votes-in-a-day)
>   [I voted more than 40 times in one UTC day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143617/i-voted-more-than-40-times-in-one-utc-day)

I have just noticed that I voted **42** times today.. I thought there was a limit of 30 + additional 10 on questions?

[image: 42 daily votes]

Comment: Looks like we have a very similar bug: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143617/168333  .  Did you click on a voting button after you hit the daily limit?

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Ah indeed. Just counted them up manually, just like you did, and it comes to 40. Thanks for input :)

Comment: @Gamecat: Voted to close (my question) as duplicate. Not deleting to register interest in the bug.

Comment: @norfavrell If you click an upvote or downvote button, do the totals change? If not, then my theory (that it's a caching thing) is proven wrong.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: I have just tried to upvote/downvote question/answer and the total doesn't change anymore (stuck at 42).

Comment: Also 42 in the pulldown, I suppose? Thanks for trying it out!