# Too many cast votes in top bar (hovering)

Tags: bug, vote-count, stack-exchange-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does someone get to cast more than 40 votes in a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/how-does-someone-get-to-cast-more-than-40-votes-in-a-day)

Hovering my mouse over my name in the bar featuring the stack-exchange button (hence the tag, but please enrich my lexicon with that bar's name), I have a few more votes cast today than I believed possible (on SO) :

[image: screenshot]

Is that worth a badge ? :')

Edit : The day being over, I'm back to 0.

Comment: A screen shot might be better here... If possible...

Comment: @Lix: Sure, incoming.

Comment: Did you vote on some posts which were later deleted?