# I was able to make one upvote on my own question even if the daily vote limit was reached

Tags: support, voting-limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does someone get to cast more than 40 votes in a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/how-does-someone-get-to-cast-more-than-40-votes-in-a-day)

Today I had already reached my daily 40 votes limit (or at least I think so, in many places I was informed of this).

Then I asked this question

[Optimize if-statement (a > 0 && b > 0 && a + b == c) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900616/optimize-if-statement-a-0-b-0-a-b-c-in-c-sharp)

After some discussion, I tried speculatively to make an upvote on an answer (provided by user **detunized**) to see what happens, and even though the orange box shown informing me that the limit was reached, the vote was cast and up until now my vote shows as submitted (the upward arrow is orange).

I also tried to vote on other answers and it didn't work.

Has anyone encountered this before or has any idea what's happening?

Comment: this likely happens because some of the posts you voted for are deleted. For an example of 52 (and even 119!) votes per day, look at [this discussion in Programmers chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5991156#5991156)

Comment: That, or you un-did one vote you had cast earlier that day.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-bydesign]: [How does someone get to cast more than 40 votes in a day?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124172/165773)

Comment: I think gnat is right. I think I downvoted a poor question which I also flagged, and it probably got deleted. I didn't unvote any of my questions. And the 'limit' message that I got when I voted for the question was probably legitimately shown because I again reached the limit.