# Why was I allowed 45 votes today?

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does someone get to cast more than 40 votes in a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/how-does-someone-get-to-cast-more-than-40-votes-in-a-day)

From what I've [read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/145631), 40 seemed to be the maximum.  Why was I able to [vote 45 times](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84873/doc) today?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

5 posts you voted on during the day were deleted, and you got those votes back.