# How did I get the Vox Populi badge?

Tags: support, badges, voting-badges

I only count about 35 votes in my votes tab.
The description says that I voted my max of 40 votes.

How is that possible?

Does this include deleted posts that I do not know about? And if that is true, do I have extra votes left for today?

Comment: I have you at 42 votes for the day in your votes summary (I can't see your votes tab, naturally).  This does include deleted posts that you voted on, which also explains how you're able to vote more than 40 times in a day.

Comment: Are you counting your votes based on your timezone or UTC? SE stores time in UTC.

Comment: @JoshMein yea. Previous to today was December 6.

Comment: Interesting @BilltheLizard So as long as people keep deleting the posts I vote on, I can continue to vote more than the "40 limit"?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  It's a known bug, but it has pretty low priority because it's *really* hard to exploit.  You practically need to be a diamond moderator.

Comment: @BillTheLizard he says, trying not to look suspicious

Comment: Wait... what? @BilltheLizard

Comment: @qwertynl I think he means that for the cycle to continue for a day, so many posts have to be deleted that it would max out a 10k users delete votes, and normal users can't delete posts, that you would have to be a mod to *really* exploit it.

Comment: @hichris123 Yes, that's what I mean.  You might get lucky and guess several posts that are going to be deleted on the same day you vote on them, but that's an edge case.  A moderator could sit and vote/delete all day if they were bored.

Comment: @RichardTingle Nothing to see here.  Move along, people. Go back to your homes.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Have you ever had one of those days? Where you just wanted to delete questions all day, and were so bored? :)

Comment: @hichris123 I'll just say that I've cast over 70 votes in a day before.

Comment: @BilltheLizard not particularly hard if you know where the roomba will strike - and that doesn't take a mod, just the right query.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess this was a caching issue on your profile page, as not long after you'd posted Bill the Lizard posted the comment:

> I have you at 42 votes for the day in your votes summary (I can't see your votes tab, naturally). This does include deleted posts that you voted on, which also explains how you're able to vote more than 40 times in a day

Several times when I've voted on a lot of posts I've started receiving the five votes left message when my profile only shows around twenty votes for the day. I'm not sure exactly what the caching rules are but sometimes I've observed delays of around thirty minutes before the profile vote count is updated. Also note that the rules for getting the badge is based on UTC days, although that is also the way your votes for the day is calculated under your profile page.

Answer (score 1):

The [votes tab in our profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes) does not list votes on posts that have been deleted, and such votes do not count towards our daily total, [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/how-does-someone-get-to-cast-more-than-40-votes-in-a-day).

So it means you reached 40 votes, the badge has been awarded, and then 5 posts you voted on have been deleted before you viewed your votes tab. You got to keep the badge, since it's not taken away after being awarded.

Comment: This seems to imply that if I vote 30 times, then five posts are deleted, and then I vote 10 more times, that I wouldn't get the Vox Populi badge.  Are you trying to say that?  My understanding of "such votes do not count" is that they don't count toward your *limit*, not your *total* (as shown on the profile summary)

Comment: @Nathaniel that's a good question, and I'm not really sure about it.