# Out of votes for the day but missing one vote for Vox Populi badge

Tags: support, badges

I'm told I've run out of votes. But it also says I'm missing one vote for the Vox Populi badge (I'm at 39/40).

These two statements seem to contradict each other.

What's going on?

Comment: Should probably be duped directly to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes.

Comment: Maybe, but some will not see how the chain links to the almighty FAQ

Answer (score 5):

> - You can vote 30 times per UTC day, plus 10 more times on questions only.

from https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up.

You've voted on only 9 questions. To reach the full 40 votes, you have to vote on at least 10 questions before you start getting the "X votes left" warnings.

Comment: Actually, I tried, I can't vote on another question, nor on another answer.

Comment: right, because you waited too long to vote on a question

Answer (score 4):

You need to [vote on at least 10 questions before you vote on 25 answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes/90256#90256). Once you've voted on 25 answers the vote countdown starts and you can only vote 5 more times.

If a post is deleted the same day as your vote was cast, you get that vote back. So you can exceed the 30/40 limits if you vote on posts that are deleted.

Comment: Ok, will try that some other day. Thanks!

Comment: If you happen to vote on a lot of questions that get auto-deleted, you can easily get 20 or 30 extra votes in a day:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/how-does-someone-get-to-cast-more-than-40-votes-in-a-day